# TFS iteration backlog to show only user stories instead of tasks

Tags: tfs-2015

In TFS 2015 using the Agile process template, the **board** for the "Stories" backlog shows only stories, and the board for the current iteration shows all tasks under stories.  This makes sense for most teams.

We are breaking down our work into smaller than usual stories and thus [avoiding task breakdown](https://www.scrumalliance.org/community/articles/2009/january/a-cure-for-task-estimation-obsession), so very few of our stories have tasks.  Is there a way to show stories on the current iteration board instead of tasks, so that it looks similar to the higher-level stories board but with only the stories in the iteration?

In the end, I want to avoid a useless board like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you please share if you achieved it in doing so? Thanks.

Comment: I have not.  The closest way is to use the Board under "Stories".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered just using the Kanban/Backlog board?

My team don't use tasks at all, all our work is tracked on the Kanban board, we never use the Sprint Board.

Some teams add a "Sprint Backlog" column to show what is planned for the current sprint. Then you can collapse the "New" column until the next planning session.