# TFS 2015 Iteration board to show user stories instead of tasks

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, agile

I visited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35204788/tfs-iteration-backlog-to-show-only-user-stories-instead-of-tasks) question on StackOverflow, but there was no proper answer fulfilling the need.

Currently, in the TFS iteration board, the tasks of user stories can be dragged for changing state.

But, I have user stories, only some which have tasks while others do not have.So, in the TFS iteration board I need only User Stories to show, which can be dragged from one state to another.

Is there a way we can update the template accordingly?
Or any other way?

Comment: Your link in "this“ is broken. Assuming you are refering to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35204788/tfs-iteration-backlog-to-show-only-user-stories-instead-of-tasks  Have updated your question.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be achieved by now. You can add a feature request in [User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services).